# Keycloak - AuthenticationFlowException: Not found serialized context in clientSession

Tags: keycloak

I am getting this exception when trying to log in from an external IDP using Keycloak.

```
Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException: Not found serialized context in clientSession
    at org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.broker.AbstractIdpAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractIdpAuthenticator.java:66)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:200)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:853)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:722)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:286)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.brokerLoginFlow(LoginActionsService.java:753)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.postBrokerLoginGet(LoginActionsService.java:687)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor866.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The following page is displayed when error occurs.

[image]

I know for sure that the user credentials are correct. I have also checked the token mappers for the IDP and everything seems correct.

So what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I had the post login flow set to `first broker login` in my Identity Provider settings. It should be left blank for my Identity Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Realm Settings` -> `Login(tab)`
Try to turn off the `Email as username` parameter.
It it will resolve your issue - then you need to create proper mapper in `Mappers` tab in identity provider configuration. After your new mapper will properly pass emails as usernames you can turn `Email as username` on.

[image]